# Unable to add a cross-filter to a report

Tags: reporting, account, contact, custom-report-type

[image]

I am trying to create a report of Accounts with no Contacts. No matter what I try, though, I am unable to add a cross-filter to make this happen. In fact, none of the filter options from the dropdown are available; they are all greyed out. I am sure this is something simple that I am missing, but I can't figure it out.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi just added one

Comment: Do you have Create and Customize Reports permission on your profile?

Answer (score 0):

To add edit, or delete a cross filter in private reports:

> Legacy Folder Sharing
>
> Create and Customize Reports
>
> Enhanced Folder Sharing
>
> Create and Customize Reports

To add edit, or delete a cross filter in private and public reports:

> Legacy Folder Sharing
>
> Report Builder
>
> Enhanced Folder Sharing
>
> Report Builder OR Report Builder (Lightning Experience)

Refer the [Create a Cross Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_cross_filters_create.htm&type=5)